# "Long frame times are an indication of jank"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, rendering, timeline

While playing in web-developer in Chrome, I ran into this `Long frame times are an indication of jank` problem. After some experiments I still didn't get the point.
Then I created a new `.html` file with the following (almost empty) content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Empty</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p"></p>
<script>document.querySelector("#p").innerHTML = Date.now();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*(`Date.now()` is to define that Chrome surely will repaint something)*

…opened it in Chrome's `Incognito mode` and reloaded page several times in a different way (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and that third thing).

And there were situations, when frame duration was like 5 or 20 seconds or even 2 minutes!
*(Have to say: I didn't have to wait for anything for 2 minutes.)*
I can't understand, what might have take five seconds to load here.

The problem fires casually without any visible logic, so I need help to manage it.

---

[This course](https://www.udacity.com/courses/ud860) gives me the basic understanding of Chrome's rendering algorithms, but that guys have different version of console, so it helped a little.

---

Screenshot after the question is asked. `17.3 mins`:

[image]

Comment: call `document.close()` after, but really don't use `document.write()` unless you have to

Comment: @dandavis: Nothing. Created new `<p>` and did `getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML = Date.now()` on it. There is still a jank.

Comment: I think now, that it is not actually a problem, but some sort of defect in Chrome. Because it really does nothing at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this using a simple [JSBIN page](https://output.jsbin.com/vevunatiye) - using the code in your question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Empty</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p"></p>
<script>document.querySelector("#p").innerHTML = Date.now();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter how many times I run this I have no issues. It is worth noting that there is always a bar for frame time - but it can represent "Idle Frame Time".

I don't get any jank warnings.

[image: Performance in Chrome 60.0.3112.101 (64 bit)]

If you still have this issue, please provide an example - especially if there is anything else on your page that could be a factor.

Comment: Looks like it is not an issue anymore. I could not reproduce is either.